# Bigcommerce Stencil Custom Login page not working on SAFARI/OPERA

Tags: authentication, safari, bigcommerce

I have created a custom login page that is fully working on firefox and chrome. This page is totally customized and needs to login the customer, verify email and password and redirect to another page.

With the help of the enpoint /remote.php?w=expressCheckoutLogin I can send email and password to BC, get the confirmation and then I redirect the request to another page. 
This page needs to show the customer id verifing that customer is logged in and proceeding with the page functionalities.

This is fully working in Firefox and Chrome (IE not tested), but in SAFARI it doesn't complete the login. 
In Safari, the fetch request gives a status == 1 and the login is done, but when I go to the new page the customer id isn't available. It seems that the customer is not logged in (even if the status is good). I repeat, this happen only in SAFARI and OPERA (not firefox and chrome).
There are some Javascript incompatibilities with the two browsers?

I'm using a MAC and the latest version of cornerstone 2.2.1

Do someone knows what causes this mysterious behavior?
This is my code for the call:

```
fetch('/remote.php?w=expressCheckoutLogin',{   
 headers: {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 },
method: 'POST',
body: 'login_email='+login_email+'&login_pass='+login_password
})
.then(response => response.json().then(json => {
  if(json.status == 1) {
     window.location = '/sell-checkout-1/' 
  } else { 
    // manage error
    // .... //
  }
}))
.catch((error) => {console.error(error)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch isn't supported in Opera and older versions of Safari. I'd recommend checking the version of Safari you're testing with:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

You could use a polyfill, but a better option might be to use the customer login API instead of sending the email and password in the request:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#/introduction/customer-login-api